# use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at Extract data from a spreadshit.pl line 8

Tags: perl

I have perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Spreadsheet::Read;

my $workbook = ReadData ("test.xls");
print $workbook->[1]{A3} . "\n";
```

And get this error: **use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at Extract data from a spreadshit.pl line 8.**

Please advice.

Comment: looks like the cell is empty. you can use `print $workbook->[1]{A5}."\n" if($workbook->[1]{A5});`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know whether your cell contains data, usually you do something like

```
print $workbook->[1]{A3} . "\n" if defined $workbook->[1]{A3};
```

You need the 'defined' otherwise things like '0' will not print.

Another way, if you still want to print an empty line and in more modern language:

```
use v5.10;
say $workbook->[1]{A3} // '';
```

*say* is like print but adds a new line, *//*, the slash slash operator, uses the left item if it is defined, otherwise the right one.

But yeah, uninitialized value just means your variable is undef.

PS. You probably want to change you script name to spread*sheet*.pl ...